# Tradeoff between building own distributed system and using kubernetes to deploy my application

Tags: kubernetes, web-deployment, distributed-system

I’m proposing a project to my school supervisor, which is to improve our current server to be more fault tolerant, easily scaling and able to handle high traffic.
I have a plan to build a distributed system starting from deploying our server to different PCs and implement caching and load balancing, etc.
But I want to know whether Kubernetes already can satisfy my objective？ what are the tradeoff between using Kubernetes and building own distributed system to deploy applications？

Our applications are built with Django and most are likely used by students such course planner or search/recommend systems.

Comment: This depends a lot on how your application looks like at the moment. Is it able to run in a fault tolerant / load sharing way?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give any details of your app, so I'll provide some generic thoughts. Shortly speaking, Kubernetes gives you scheduling, load balancing and (sort of) high availability for free. You still have to plan proper application architecture but Kubernetes gives you a good starting point where you can say like "ok, I want this number of app containers to run on this number of nodes". It also gives you internal load balancing and DNS resolution.

Of course, the tradeoff is that you have to learn Kubernetes and Docker up to some certain point. But I wouldn't say it's too hard for enthusiast.

Comment: Hi, our applications are built with Django and most are used by students such as course planning, search and recommendation system.

Comment: In that case Kubernetes should be very good for you. It will also teach your students modern technologies they will face in their careers.

Answer (score 1):

> I’m proposing a project to my school supervisor, which is to improve our current server to be more fault tolerant, easily scaling and able to handle high traffic.

This is a great idea. What you really want to do here is to use as many existing tools as you can, to let you **focus** on improving the *core functionality* of your **current server** - e.g. serving your users with your business logic and data and increase availability of this.

Focusing on your *core functionality* means that you should NOT do, e.g.

- NOT write your own memory allocation algorithm or garbage collection
- NOT write you own operating system
- NOT write your own container scheduler (e.g. what Kubernetes can do for you)

> I have a plan to build a distributed system starting from deploying our server to different PCs and implement caching and load balancing

Most applications deployed on Kubernetes or that have your *availability* requirements actually *should be a **distributed system*** - e.g. be composed of more than one instance, designed for elasticity and resiliency.

> what are the tradeoff between using Kubernetes and building own distributed system to deploy applications?

Kubernetes is a tool, almost an distributed operating system that e.g. schedules containerized apps to a server farm. It is a tool that can help you a lot when developing and designing your distribued application that should follow the [Twelve Factor principles](https://12factor.net/).